# Как настроить 3G модем InterTelecom в Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu

Как настроить 3G модем InterTelecom в Ubuntu 12.04? Последовательность моих действий:1. Открываю апплет настроек сети в верхней панели рабочего стола.2. Выбираю EditConnection.3. В открывшемся окне NetWork Connections выбираю вкладку Mobile Broadband. Нажимаю Add/Continue/выбираю свою страну/провайдера (InterTelecom)/Apply и далее в окне Number: #777 Username: IT, Password: IT. Все. Не работает. После установки системы никаких дополнительных пакетов не ставил.

Answer (score 2):

Откройте терминал и не втыкая модема наберите lsusb - увидите список девайсов, присутствующих в системе. Воткните модем и повторите процедуру - увидите там и свой свисток. Запишите его ID на бумажку :-). Теперь наберите в терминале dmesg | grep usb - Ваш девайс либо будет там как ttyUSB *(ttyAMA*), либо нет - если система не знает, чо это такое. А затем если вы так или иначе подключены к сети, то наберите sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch . Перезагрузка, и если подключения через Ваш модем нет, то в Сети гуглите, как пользоваться этой утилиткой (с её помощью свисток перевоится из режима usb-storage в режим модема...)