# Настроить модем в Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

Установил Ubuntu 15.10 и начал осваиваться.. Первое что нужно сделать — естественно подключить интернет. 
Я временно вынужден пользоваться модемом UML 290 от Интертелеком . В Windows пришлось скачивать драйвера отдельно, но под Linux их нет; ONLY WINDOWS сказали мне в тех. поддержке. Я совсем новичок (совсем-совсем). 
Пока что у меня стоит и Windows 7 (да-да, две ОС, пока я ещё не определился).
Нагуглил я вот что:

— lsusb команду. Да, она выводит мой модем, или, по крайней мере, я так думаю. Если извлечь модем, то выделенное в терминале устройство пропадает.

— Файл справа (см. скриншот один) это тоже нагуглил. Пишут что там описание устройств или что-то в этом роде, по этому просто предоставляю скриншотом строки моей модели модема, ибо сам я тут бессилен :)

— Слева на первом "скрине" текстовый файл. Это VID, PID и модель модема, которые я скопировал из диспетчера устройств в Win7.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
возможно, что это также поможет (см. скрин2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это если пытаться настроить через Network Manager. То есть "какой-то" модем все же определятся.

Я не знаю честно говоря что делать. Предоставляю сведения в надежде на помощь опытных юзеров.

P.S. — Непосредственно на Ubuntu нет интернет соединения, по этому я не смог поставить пакеты которые описывают в статьях, а-ля gppp или что-то в этом роде.

P.S.S. — Мой провайдер использует технологию CDMA.

UPD: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытка через wvdial. Неработающее соединение..

Comment: Когдато использовал интертелеком на Ubuntu. Просто создайте pppoe (вроде) соединение с параметрами №телефона #777 , user IT, pass IT. Все работало "из коробки" без дополнительных танцев с бубнами)

Comment: Не работает.. Оно как бы есть, но в списке доступных для подключения нету.

Comment: Очень надеюсь что всё же найдется человек с решением. Убинта мне понравилась, уже думал Windows снести полностью, но без интернета много не сделаешь :(

Comment: У вас там в списке появилось созданное подключение то? Вы создавали DSL подключение, так?

Comment: Я ничего не создавал, кроме Mobile Broadband соединений по мануалу.. Ну они не работают.

Comment: Забыл добавить: да, в списке появилось. Там где Edit Connections.

Comment: Вот так как тут делаю: http://linuxsoid.com/blog/nastraivaem_3g_internet_ot_intertelekom_v_ubuntu_14_04_lts/2014-09-10-167 ... В итоге оно не появляется как на последнем скрине.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx-G-Sn6IhY  Я подключал модем как обычный DSL когдато. правда давно лет 5 назад) Вот попробуйте создать таким образом и просто подключить соединение. попробуйте.

Comment: Сделал как в видео, этот DSL, но у меня в списке (как в конце видео) не появилось подключение. Ввел пароль и имя пользователя. Ни-че-го.. Похоже безнадежно пытаться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33867/discussion-between-moonvvell-and-drfels).

Comment: @drfels какой у Вас оператор связи (провайдер услуги cdma)?

Comment: Интертелеком у меня.

Answer (score 1):

раз модем виден и опознан распишу как это сделал я на Xubuntu для MTS connect. постараюсь расписать подробно и с пояснениями (возможно Вам это покажется трудным но на самом деле все очень просто, тут дело привычки. мне просто не нравится по менюшкам лазить и ярлыки плодить. **почти все делается через терминал**).

1. используя любой текстовый редактор в папке Documents создаем файл cdmainet.sh с следующим содержанием  (можно скопипастить отсюда и изменить то что прокомметировано если необходимо):

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> mkdir /etc/chatscripts
> rm /etc/chatscripts/pap
> touch /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo 'ABORT           BUSY' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo 'ABORT           VOICE' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo 'ABORT           "NO CARRIER"' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo 'ABORT           "NO DIALTONE"' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo 'ABORT           "NO DIAL TONE"' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo '""              ATZ' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo 'OK              ATDT\T' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> echo 'CONNECT         ""' >> /etc/chatscripts/pap
> rm /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
> touch /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
> echo 'mobile      mtsconnect        internet' >> /etc/ppp/chap-secrets # в одинарных кавычках то что мне нужно для MTS. Вам, возможно, придется погуглить.
> rm /etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> touch /etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo '/dev/ttyUSB0' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo '230400' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect # число в кавычках может быть другим, зависит от оператора
> echo 'crtscts' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'modem' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'noccp' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'novj' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> ch1="'"
> ch2="#"
> ch3='"'
> ch4='777' # номер телефона для установки связи. внимание!!! если номер содержит знак решетки тут его писать не нужно, он указан ранее
> echo "connect $ch3/usr/sbin/chat -e -v -f /etc/chatscripts/pap -T $ch1$ch2$ch4$ch1$ch3" >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'noauth' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'user mobile' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'remotename mtsconnect' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'usepeerdns' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'defaultroute' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'debug' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'updetach' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'lcp-echo-interval 20' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'lcp-echo-failure 3' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'persist' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> echo 'maxfail 0' >>/etc/ppp/peers/mtsconnect
> pppd call mtsconnect # и сразу звоним
> ```

2. открыть терминал
3. получаем привилегии root

> sudo -s

(если спросит пароль то вводим ваш пароль (в вашем случае - пароль пользователя drfels))

4. устанвка **ppp** (возможно он уже установлен). пишем

> apt-get install ppp

5. переходим в папку /home/drfels/Documents

> cd /home/drfels/Documents

6. делаем файл cdmainet.sh исполняемым (аналог cmd и bat в Windows)

> chmod 777 cdmainet.sh

все готово. далее для установки соединения (через терминал)

> cd /home/drfels/Documents
>
> sudo ./cdmainet.sh

или можно

> sudo pon mtsconnect

для разрыва соединения

> sudo poff mtsconnect

напоминаю: делалось для MTS connect по инструкциям от http://skeletor.org.ua/?p=788. Вам, возможно, что-то нужно будет выяснить отдельно.

P.S.: в нижнем скриншоте может быть **Installed CDMA device** или Ваш модем.
P.S.2: на счет модема и устройств в целом: не всегда то что написано (наклеено/нарисовано и т.п.) на устройстве соответствует тому что есть на самом деле. тут помогут команды типа:
**lshw** (с ней вы уже знакомы), **lspci**, **dmidecode**.

P.S.3: добавочка. прочтите это
[Как настроить 3G модем InterTelecom в Ubuntu 12.04?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/347681/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-3g-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC-intertelecom-%D0%B2-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)

Comment: Да, попробую, спасибо. Не по теме: что означает эта точка перед / или после него ? ./ и /.

Comment: @drfels ./cdmainet.sh значит выполнить файл cdmainet.sh, находящийся в текущей папке. в эту папку вы попали командой **cd**  (относительный путь к файлу cdmainet.sh). абсолютный путь к файлу **cdmainet.sh** будет  **/home/drfels/Documents/cdmainet.sh**

Comment: Могу я с вами связаться как-то попроще? Много вопросов.

Comment: @drfels мой skype: tarcomevl

Comment: Есть ВК? У меня нет Skype.

Comment: @drfels меня нет в социальных сетях. но тут есть чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Жаль (. Через ваш вариант не получилось. Но wvdial обнаружил мой модем и через команду wvdialconfig создал конфигурацию для него. Я вписал в неё свои данные (номер, логин и пароль) и ввёл sudo wvdial . Он подключился, что меня очень обрадовало, потом что раньше не получалось. Как потом оказало (когда я открыл браузер и ввёл в адресную строку gooogle.com) — соединение ложное, или, можно сказать, не действительное.. Что-то видимо не так я сделал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33972/discussion-between--and-drfels).